# Save oracle table data into local machine in excel sheet

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to extract data from a table on a daily basis and save it in my local machine in a excel sheet.

Comment: There are many ways. How automatic does the process need to be? Does the product need to be in Excel's format, or merely something which Excel will open and format legibly?

Comment: Product needs to be saved in excel format.

Comment: Yes, but directly? Creating a CSV file on the fly is easy. Importing CSV into Excel and saving it is XLS(X) is easy. Having Oracle spit out an XLS(X) without manual actions needn't be too difficult, but the exact path you take depends on your needs. Google `pl sql write to excel file` for some examples, and consider asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to extract data from a table on a daily basis

You could use **[DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php)** to create a **job** and **schedule** to run daily.

For example, the below job will run every hour:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (JOB_NAME => 'test_full_job_definition');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'test_full_job_definition',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
  6      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
  8      end_date        => NULL,
  9      enabled         => TRUE,
 10      comments        => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT JOB_NAME, ENABLED FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where job_name ='TEST_FULL_JOB_DEFINITION'
  2  /

JOB_NAME                                 ENABL
---------------------------------------- -----
TEST_FULL_JOB_DEFINITION                 TRUE

SQL>
```

> save it in my local machine in a excel sheet

This is a *frequently asked question*, and people often get confused between a **CSV** file and a **Microsoft Excel** file. Generating a CSV file could be as easy as to **spool** it using **SQL*Plus**. For writing the output into an Excel file, you need to do it **programmatically**.

You could use the following [code](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/as_xlsx11.txt) developed by [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package as_xlsx
is
/**********************************************
**
** Author: Anton Scheffer
** Date: 19-02-2011
** Website: http://technology.amis.nl/blog
** See also: http://technology.amis.nl/blog/?p=10995
**
** Changelog:
**   Date: 21-02-2011
**     Added Aligment, horizontal, vertical, wrapText
**   Date: 06-03-2011
**     Added Comments, MergeCells, fixed bug for dependency on NLS-settings
**   Date: 16-03-2011
**     Added bold and italic fonts
**   Date: 22-03-2011
**     Fixed issue with timezone's set to a region(name) instead of a offset
**   Date: 08-04-2011
**     Fixed issue with XML-escaping from text
**   Date: 27-05-2011
**     Added MIT-license
**   Date: 11-08-2011
**     Fixed NLS-issue with column width
**   Date: 29-09-2011
**     Added font color
**   Date: 16-10-2011
**     fixed bug in add_string
**   Date: 26-04-2012
**     Fixed set_autofilter (only one autofilter per sheet, added _xlnm._FilterDatabase)
**     Added list_validation = drop-down 
**   Date: 27-08-2013
**     Added freeze_pane
**
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Copyright (C) 2011, 2012 by Anton Scheffer

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.

******************************************************************************
******************************************** */
--
  type tp_alignment is record
    ( vertical varchar2(11)
    , horizontal varchar2(16)
    , wrapText boolean
    );
--
  procedure clear_workbook;
--
  procedure new_sheet( p_sheetname varchar2 := null );
--
  function OraFmt2Excel( p_format varchar2 := null )
  return varchar2;
--
  function get_numFmt( p_format varchar2 := null )
  return pls_integer;
--
  function get_font
    ( p_name varchar2
    , p_family pls_integer := 2
    , p_fontsize number := 11
    , p_theme pls_integer := 1
    , p_underline boolean := false
    , p_italic boolean := false
    , p_bold boolean := false
    , p_rgb varchar2 := null -- this is a hex ALPHA Red Green Blue value
    )
  return pls_integer;
--
  function get_fill
    ( p_patternType varchar2
    , p_fgRGB varchar2 := null -- this is a hex ALPHA Red Green Blue value
    )
  return pls_integer;
--
  function get_border
    ( p_top varchar2 := 'thin'
    , p_bottom varchar2 := 'thin'
    , p_left varchar2 := 'thin'
    , p_right varchar2 := 'thin'
    )
/*
none
thin
medium
dashed
dotted
thick
double
hair
mediumDashed
dashDot
mediumDashDot
dashDotDot
mediumDashDotDot
slantDashDot
*/
  return pls_integer;
--
  function get_alignment
    ( p_vertical varchar2 := null
    , p_horizontal varchar2 := null
    , p_wrapText boolean := null
    )
/* horizontal
center
centerContinuous
distributed
fill
general
justify
left
right
*/
/* vertical
bottom
center
distributed
justify
top
*/
  return tp_alignment;
--
  procedure cell
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_value number
    , p_numFmtId pls_integer := null
    , p_fontId pls_integer := null
    , p_fillId pls_integer := null
    , p_borderId pls_integer := null
    , p_alignment tp_alignment := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure cell
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_value varchar2
    , p_numFmtId pls_integer := null
    , p_fontId pls_integer := null
    , p_fillId pls_integer := null
    , p_borderId pls_integer := null
    , p_alignment tp_alignment := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure cell
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_value date
    , p_numFmtId pls_integer := null
    , p_fontId pls_integer := null
    , p_fillId pls_integer := null
    , p_borderId pls_integer := null
    , p_alignment tp_alignment := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure hyperlink
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_url varchar2
    , p_value varchar2 := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure comment
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_text varchar2
    , p_author varchar2 := null
    , p_width pls_integer := 150  -- pixels
    , p_height pls_integer := 100  -- pixels
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure mergecells
    ( p_tl_col pls_integer -- top left
    , p_tl_row pls_integer
    , p_br_col pls_integer -- bottom right
    , p_br_row pls_integer
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure list_validation
    ( p_sqref_col pls_integer
    , p_sqref_row pls_integer
    , p_tl_col pls_integer -- top left
    , p_tl_row pls_integer
    , p_br_col pls_integer -- bottom right
    , p_br_row pls_integer
    , p_style varchar2 := 'stop' -- stop, warning, information
    , p_title varchar2 := null
    , p_prompt varchar := null
    , p_show_error boolean := false
    , p_error_title varchar2 := null
    , p_error_txt varchar2 := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure list_validation
    ( p_sqref_col pls_integer
    , p_sqref_row pls_integer
    , p_defined_name varchar2
    , p_style varchar2 := 'stop' -- stop, warning, information
    , p_title varchar2 := null
    , p_prompt varchar := null
    , p_show_error boolean := false
    , p_error_title varchar2 := null
    , p_error_txt varchar2 := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure defined_name
    ( p_tl_col pls_integer -- top left
    , p_tl_row pls_integer
    , p_br_col pls_integer -- bottom right
    , p_br_row pls_integer
    , p_name varchar2
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    , p_localsheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure set_column_width
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_width number
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure set_column
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_numFmtId pls_integer := null
    , p_fontId pls_integer := null
    , p_fillId pls_integer := null
    , p_borderId pls_integer := null
    , p_alignment tp_alignment := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure set_row
    ( p_row pls_integer
    , p_numFmtId pls_integer := null
    , p_fontId pls_integer := null
    , p_fillId pls_integer := null
    , p_borderId pls_integer := null
    , p_alignment tp_alignment := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure freeze_rows
    ( p_nr_rows pls_integer := 1
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure freeze_cols
    ( p_nr_cols pls_integer := 1
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure freeze_pane
    ( p_col pls_integer
    , p_row pls_integer
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  procedure set_autofilter
    ( p_column_start pls_integer := null
    , p_column_end pls_integer := null
    , p_row_start pls_integer := null
    , p_row_end pls_integer := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
--
  function finish
  return blob;
--
  procedure save
    ( p_directory varchar2
    , p_filename varchar2
    );
--
  procedure query2sheet
    ( p_sql varchar2
    , p_column_headers boolean := true
    , p_directory varchar2 := null
    , p_filename varchar2 := null
    , p_sheet pls_integer := null
    );
```

**Note :** It is a huge code with more than 90k PL/SQL lines of code, so I can't post the entire code here due to restriction of 30k characters. Only posting the important procedures, functions and the package details. Please follow the code link to get the entire code.

Comment: Hey Lalit,  I am aware about dbms_scheduler part. The problem with me is how I send table's data to my desktop's C drive. Can you please suggest me some shorter method. I appreciate your efforts but I have to do this by today only and above code will take much tym to analyse and implement. Hope to hear frm u soon.

Comment: @Famy I think implementing the above code would not be time consuming, because there are examples provided how to use it. You just need to pass the directory name etc.

Answer (score 0):

the least demanding way would be to daly insert table data into some temp table by some scheduled job

```
create table myexportable as (select sysdate exportdate, q.* from mytable q)
```

resp.

```
insert into myexportable (select sysdate exportdate, q.* from mytable q)
```

and then export that data  using SQL Plus

```
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 10000;
set pagesize 10000; 
set heading off;
set feed 0;
set trimspool on;
set colsep '|'; 

spool exptable.out;

select * from myexportable where trunc(exportdate) = trunc(sysdate)
/
quit;
```

and them at least import pipe delimited text file into excel.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B The code given below is extracting data into csv format in my local machine. but any idea how to schedule it?

Comment: spool C:\daily\excel\excel\emp3.csv

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000   

SET FEEDBACK      OFF
SET TERMOUT   OFF
SET PAGESIZE  0
SET LINESIZE  2000
 
DECLARE 
CURSOR c_emp is

SELECT as_mst_doc_name from swiftdba.as_doc_type$t;
begin 
 for r_emp in c_emp
 loop
 dbms_output.put_line(r_emp.as_mst_doc_name);
 end loop;
 
 
 end;
 /

SPOOL OFF